# Getting a NoInitialContextException when connecting a JMXConnector

Tags: java, exception, jmx

I need to connect a java aplication to an MBean server, but I'm having trouble getting JMXConnector to work.

I am getting a NoInitialContextException when I try to run this:

```
try
{
    if(user != null)
    {
        HashMap environment = new HashMap();
        environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, new String[] {user, password});
        connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(location, environment);
    }
    else
    {
        connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(location, null);
    }

    beanServer = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw new ConnectException("Failed to connect to " + location + ": " + e.getMessage());
}
```

It happens when I use an username and password, although I cannot test without one because the test server I have has to be authenticated.

Edit: I am using java6 SE. No related jars added.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which server you are trying to connect, but here is an example for [weblogic](http://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/sample_weblogic_jmx_client) . I suspect, your JMXServiceURL is not correct, it changes based on Mbeanserver you are trying to connect.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think so. The url was given to me and it works with JConsole. Looking at it the server is indeed weblogic (it's written in the url).

Comment: It seems you are missing javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "weblogic.management.remote", in environment. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

As thinksteep said, you can try that:

```
Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<String, Object>();
env.put(JMXConnectorServerFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES,              "com.sun.jmx.remote.protocol");
```

And later you can connect with:

```
jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(address), env);
```